# Open XML Reading Excel file does not enter loop to read excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I have a scenario where I need to read Excel file in an MVC Application, I need this to run on the server, therefore I am using Open XML, I have a issue where my code does not enter the loop of rows in the sheet, please see my code below and advice on how I can rectify my code.

```
if (file.ContentLength > 0)
{
    string path = file.FileName;    
    using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(path, false))
    {
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = doc.WorkbookPart;
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
        SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();

        foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
        {
            foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
            {
                string text = c.CellValue.Text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas, your help will be greatly appreciated, I have been trying multiple approaching but I am not getting in the foreach loop fr some odd reason.

I am using Excel 2013 and please see below image of my workbook.

[image: Here is my Excel sheet template]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using following code which works fine for me.

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(sFileNameWithPath, false))
{
    WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = GetWorksheetPart(workbookPart, sSheetName);

    SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();

    bool bHasChildren = sheetData.HasChildren;
    if (bHasChildren)
    {
        for (int iCounter1 = 1; iCounter1 < sheetData.Elements<Row>().Count(); iCounter1++)
        {
            Row rDataRow = sheetData.Elements<Row>().ElementAt(iCounter1);
            for (int iCounter = 0; iCounter < rDataRow.ChildElements.Count; iCounter++)
            {
                Cell oCell = (Cell)rDataRow.ChildElements[iCounter];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Or you can use your code with following change

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(sFileNameWithPath, false))
{
    WorkbookPart workbookPart = doc.WorkbookPart;

    string relId = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().First(s => "Claims".Equals(s.Name)).Id;
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(relId);

    SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();

    foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
    {
        foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
        {
            string text = c.CellValue.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I have used the excel sheet name "Claims", so check whether it works and if yes; put it in another function to make it generic

Comment: Its still not working, its doesn't enter the for loop, also where is the GetWorksheetPart(workbookPart, sSheetName); method defined? I have tried many different approaches,no luck. The HasChildrenSheets retuns false, therefore it skips the loop, if I remove the HasChildrenSheets code, it enters the expression but not the code in the loop

Comment: That function is nothing, but returns the worksheet private static WorksheetPart GetWorksheetPart(WorkbookPart workbookPart, string sheetName)
        {
            string relId = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().First(s => sheetName.Equals(s.Name)).Id;
            return (WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(relId);
        }

Comment: I am still battling to enter the loop, I have no idea why

Comment: What is the version on Excel? Also is it possible to share the excel template (may be with junk data? Because the code above works well for me...

Comment: I am using Excel 2013, I have also updated post above and added excel template

Comment: Hi Papi, I have edited my previous answer which uses your function with Excel Sheet Name. I have checked it and found working... Let me know if that works for you as well.

Comment: WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First(); is the line which is not getting any worksheetPart...

Comment: I am now getting an error "Sequence contains no matching element" on this line -- string relId = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().First(s => "Claims".Equals(s.Name)).Id;, I changed it to use .FirstOrDefalut() and it throws a "Object reference null exception, any ideas?

Comment: As far as you have a work sheet with name "Claims", it should work.

Comment: I managed to get it right, I copied the spreadsheet into another workbook and it worked, I am not sure what is wrong with my initial spreadsheet. I can now go into the loop and get the rows and cells, could you direct me to a post where I can map the data to a model in my code, or perhaps a data table, what do you suggest.

Comment: Depending upon what is the use post parsing, you can decide the same. I usually convert parse the data and fill a DataSet so it can be used for further processing.

Comment: Thanks you, I will use that approach.